# sock failed (2: No such file or directory) - django + gunicorn + virtualenv + centos7

Tags: django, gunicorn, virtualenv, centos7

Estoy intentando desplegar una aplicación Django en CentOS7 usando gunicorn y ngnix para atender las peticiones.

Seguí una guía de internet (Digital ocean) para CentOS7 (ver URL más abajo), he seguido la guía lo más apegado posible y cuando se supone que debería ver la aplicación Django, nginx me arroja un error 502.

**Al parecer** algo anda mal con gunicorn, no crea un archivo **.sock**, no se como arreglar este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**SO:** CentOS 7

**Python:** Python 3.6 (Corriendo Django con un virtualenv python3.6)

**Django:** 2.0

**Gunicorn:** 19....

**nginx**

**SGBD:** SQLite3 (no necesito MySQL u otro SGBD por ahora)

Este es el error que muestra el log de **nginx**

```
2018/01/07 02:15:05 [crit] 1284#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/django/reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.104, server: 192.168.1.105, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services.sock:/", host: "192.168.1.105"
```

Este es el error que muestra **gunicorn**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usé esta guía: [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7#install-the-packages-from-epel-and-the-centos-repositories)

En **/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=django
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/reynaldev_services
ExecStart=/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/django/reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services.sock reynaldev_services.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Notas:**
Nginx está corriendo sin problemas

SELinux deshabilitado

firewall deshabilitado

Ejecutando Django (usando *python manage.py runserver*.....) corre sin problemas

Ejecutando *gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application* puedo acceder sin problemas

Ejecutando desde el usuario django (sudo su):

> /home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/django/reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services.sock reynaldev_services.wsgi:application

```
[root@localhost django]# /home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/django/reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services.sock reynaldev_services.wsgi:application
[2018-01-22 11:31:12 -0600] [1720] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-01-22 11:31:12 -0600] [1720] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/django/reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services.sock (1720)
[2018-01-22 11:31:12 -0600] [1720] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-01-22 11:31:12 -0600] [1724] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1724
[2018-01-22 11:31:12 -0600] [1724] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reynaldev_services.wsgi'
[2018-01-22 11:31:12 -0600] [1724] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1724)
[2018-01-22 11:31:12 -0600] [1720] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-01-22 11:31:12 -0600] [1720] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
[root@localhost django]#
```

Comment: Al parecer es un problema de permisos. Logueate como el usuario `django` y probá ejecutar `gunicorn` a mano y fijate que pasa: `/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/django/reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services.sock reynaldev_services.wsgi:application`
 Si da error, agregalo a tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, agregado.

Comment: El problema es otro: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reynaldev_services.wsgi'`. Al parecer está buscando `reynaldev_services.wsgi` en un lugar incorrecto. Ese lugar es relativo al directorio donde corre gunicorn. Podrías agregarle a gunicorn el parametro: `--chdir /path/to/project`.

Comment: No existe **reynaldev_services.wsgi** desde la carpeta raiz del proyecto django (reynaldev_services) solo wsgi.py (en reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services/wsgi.py)

¿Qué debería modificar? Recordando que seguí la guía de **Digital ocean**

Comment: `reynaldev_services.wsgi` es un nombre de módulo, no de un archivo. Por eso no lo encontras. Podés decirme la ruta completa donde está ese archivo `wsgi.py`?

Comment: Claro @PanchoJay, es: **/home/django/reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services/wsgi.py** de hecho el proyecto está en **GitHub**  (https://github.com/Reynald0/reynaldev_services)
Por tanto la ruta raíz es **/home/django/**

Comment: Logueate como el usuario `django` y probá ejecutar gunicorn a mano y fijate que pasa: `/home/django/reynaldev_services/myvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/django/reynaldev_services/reynaldev_services.sock  --chdir /home/django/reynaldev_services/ reynaldev_services.wsgi:application`. Notese que agregué el parámetro `chdir`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72116/discussion-between-pancho-jay-and-reynald0).